# Error when loging into Preview for Cognitive Services Speech Containers

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

When I used the provided credentials for logging into the container registry by using the following command:

> docker login "private registry" - u -p

I get the following error:

> unauthorized: authentication required

Maybe I need new credentials or are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Request access to the container registry
Fill out and submit the [Cognitive Services Speech Containers Request form](https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR_XtneHaNtlEotgitK6YrZlUNTdBVVYyVlBWRjYxS1dLWjFDRUs3ODRVSSQlQCN0PWcu) to request access to the container.

The form requests information about you, your company, and the user scenario for which you'll use the container. After you've submitted the form, the Azure Cognitive Services team reviews it to ensure that you meet the criteria for access to the private container registry.

If your request is approved, you'll receive an email with instructions that describe how to obtain your credentials and access the private container registry.

[image]

Please follow the below link to install and run speech service containers.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-container-howto?tabs=stt%2Ccsharp